# How to set default state to my aws ecs service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm new at AWS.

Before 30 minutes, I launch ecs to deploy my docker container.

Everything looks fine.

After finishing my work, I deleted cluster, task definition.

But in my ec2 console, ec2 launch every 2 minutes inifinitly.

[image]

I deleted every resource about it.

Why it launch automatically?

Is there any solution about cleaning aws ecs configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if there any autoscaling group left which may be responsible to maintain the desired state?

Comment: @MohitKumar I deleted all the autoscaling group and re-launch it, it solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your confirmation, Recreation of the associated autoscaling group which was responsible to spin up instances solved your problem.